# Erro "A Java exception has ocurred" ao rodar o driver JDBC do Postgre

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, eclipse, jdbc

Segue o meu problema:

1 - Estou usando o banco de dados Postgre 9.6.

2 - Baixei e abri no ECLIPSE um projeto com exemplo de aplicação Java com o uso de Hibernate e Postgre que o professor criou (ou seja, o código está correto)
Coloquei o jar do driver JDBC do Postgre, versão: 4.2.0.0 no Eclipse no "Java Build Path".

3 - A versão do Jdk que está instalado e vinculado ao Eclipse é a 1.7.0_80
que, eu achava que seria compatível com Postgre e o driver JDBC acima.

O erro: 
Ao executar a aplicação, o Eclipse apresenta erros:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: br/com/bd2/teste/TesteDatabase : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

E a JVM abre uma janela de alerta com essa mensagem : "A Java Exception has ocurred!"

Seguem abaixo os prints:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erros no Eclipse: O projeto em questão é o "ExemploHibernate":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E este é o código da minha classe main:

```
package br.com.bd2.teste;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import br.com.bd2.exemplo.model.Fruteira;

public class TesteDatabase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Inicializacao da fabrica de objetos
        // persistenceUnitName = "bd2", ou seja, relaciona com a conexao na
        // persistence.xml (podera ter "n" unidades de persistencia)
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("bd2_persistence_unit");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        // Os comandos a seguir devem ser executados "um por vez"
        // Inserindo...
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(new Fruteira("Fruteira"));
        em.persist(new Fruteira("Fruteira 3"));
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        // Atualizando...
        // Buscara a fruteira com id = 1. Observe o numero do id pelo pgAdmin3!
        Fruteira fruteira = em.find(Fruteira.class, 1L); 
        if (fruteira != null) {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            fruteira.setNome("Fruteira Legal");
            em.merge(fruteira);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        // Recuperando "n" objetos...
        TypedQuery<Fruteira> q = em.createQuery("SELECT f " +
                                                "FROM Fruteira f", Fruteira.class);
        for (Fruteira each : q.getResultList()) {
            System.out.println(each.toString());
        }       

        // Excluindo...
        // Buscara a fruteira com id = 1. Observe o numero do id pelo pgAdmin3!
        fruteira = em.find(Fruteira.class, 1L); 
        if (fruteira != null) {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.remove(fruteira);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }

        // Recuperando "n" objetos...
        q = em.createQuery("FROM Fruteira f", Fruteira.class);
        for (Fruteira each : q.getResultList()) {
            System.out.println(each.toString());
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: Adicione o código e o erro em forma textual, nao em foma de imagem.

Comment: Articuno, a questão não é o código fonte. É a configuração do ambiente,eé isto que eu quis mostrar: os detalhes do projeto na aba esquerda do eclipse, e a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Remove o driver, baixa de novo e readiciona, pode ser que esteja apenas corrompido.

Comment: Ok Articuno. Fiz isso, baixei da fonte original inclusive, e não funcionou, permanece exatamente o mesmo erro...  Vamos tentando outras ideias. :D

Comment: Coloque a exceção em forma de texto e não screenshot. Apesar de você dizer que a versão do Java é compatível, dá pra ver pelo erro que se trata de uma incompatibilidade de versão. Reveja as propriedades do projeto em busca de diferenças de versão de compilador, de bibliotecas, etc (e sim, o código é importante para sabermos em que momento a exceção ocorre e termos uma ideia se tem a ver com o driver JDBC, com o Hibernate, etc).

Comment: Eu sou particularmente acostumado com esse erro "_unsupported major/minor_". Isso significa o que Edjane colocou na resposta: foi compilado com a JDK 8. Esse número (52.0) se refere ao formato do _class file_ ([leia mais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file?wprov=sfti1)). O Java reconhece isso lendo do quinto ao oitavo byte do arquivo (bytes 7-8 representam um _short_ com a versão _major_, que no caso é 52). Eu recomendo abandonar o Java 7 e mergulhar no Java 8 (ou mesmo no Java 9), as belezas do Java 8 compensam tudo

Answer (score 3):

Você está usando o drive do Java 8

Como você esta usando Java 7 o drive compatível é:

*PostgreSQL JDBC 4.1 Driver, 42.2.1.jre7* //essa é a última versão, caso você queira pode procurar pela 42.0.0.jre7

Você pode baixar o drive correto direto do site [PostgreSQL](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html)

Comment: O driver JDBC que estou usando é do Java 8?

Comment: @LucasPletsch Aparentemente sim.

Comment: Sim, é só dá uma olhada na documentação!

Comment: Ok. Eu fui aqui: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html  e baixei um driver jdbc 4.0 que é suportado até pela jdk 6. E o erro persiste. Já posso enlouquecer? kkkk

Comment: Para o Java 7, tem que ser JDBC 4.1 Você tentou esse: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.2.1.jre7.jar

Comment: Edjane e Piovezan, acho que eu descobri: acho que a versão do Hibernate que eu baixei é a 5.2. E ela só suporta Java 8 pra cima. *-*

Comment: _"Current Version 42.2.1
This is the current version of the driver. Unless you have unusual requirements (running old applications or JVMs), this is the driver you should be using. (...) If you are using Java 7 then you should use the JDBC 4.1 version."_

Comment: Não temos como saber se é o Hibernate ou o JDBC porque o log da exceção que você postou está incompleto.

Comment: Vou baixar uma versão mais antiga do Hibernate, que rode com Java 7 amanhã e testo. Não atualizo pro Java 8 porque teria que atualizar meu Eclipse também, e não pretendo fazer isso essa semana. Tem muitas questões de compatibilidade envolvidas aí. Enfim, obrigado pessoal. Abraço!

Comment: Piovezan, pior que eu coloquei todo o log. Tem q rolar a barra embaixo pra direita pra ver tudo. :S

Comment: COloquei todo o log que aparece na console do Eclipse. Tem algo mais ?

Comment: Vou dormir, amanhã eu tento com um Hibernate mais antigo. Valeu!

Comment: Me enganei, desculpe. Esse deve ser o log todo.

Comment: Não adiantou colocar um Hibernate que suporta o Java 7. Terei que tentar outras coisas